# Are there hidden costs to buying Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I ask because I'm looking to get Dota 2, but I don't want to pay more than the upfront cost through micro-transactions in-game.

Is the game fully released yet? Is it possible to get for free?

Comment: Hi CreatorsMade, and welcome to Arqade! if Decency or torchhound's answers have helped you, you can mark one of them as an answer by clicking the check mark that appears under their vote count. This helps future visitors know which answer helped you the most, and will even give you some bonus rep points! :). Also, check out the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) if you haven't already :).

Comment: The biggest hidden cost is... time :(.

Answer (score 16):

The game is entirely free of cost to download and play. The only costs you'll pay (if you want to) are for content that does not even debatably give you an advantage in-game, such as cosmetic items, pennants to support your favorite team, or tickets to watch tournaments in-game.

You can get Dota2 [here](http://store.steampowered.com/app/570/).

Comment: You could also go to: http://www.reddit.com/r/sharedota2/ and ask for a key.
Otherwise it's a free game to play. You will once in a while get a chest (like a box in TF2) that requires a key to open. This key costs money. But you can just not open it. There are also tournaments, that cost money to spectate, if you're into that.

Comment: @Holger This is no longer accurate. There are no more dropped chests that happen.

Answer (score 2):

Dota 2 beta is currently free if you can get someone to give you a pass. You can buy a beta pass for $30 (in which case you get many cosmetics items). People in the beta are periodically given 5 passes to give to friends. The game is "F2P" and utilizes micro-in-game transactions. The store and pricing scale are very similar to Team Fortress 2.

Comment: so it is not free?

Comment: It is not free unless you can get a pass. There are tons of them so it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: I've got 12 keys to spare at the moment (no advertisement) and heard the same from multiple friends. There are multiple sites now that offer give-aways, it should be easy getting a key there.

Comment: Sentry's example is a common one. The Dota 2 beta pass saturation is unfortunately causing a lot of smurfing.

Comment: @CreatorsMade: So many free passes have been given out that it's insanely easy to find someone willing to give you a free Dota 2 pass.  Even if you can't, they sell for $0.03 on the steam market.

Answer (score 1):

The game is already released, and it is a F2P Game, meaning there is no need to spend money on the game (unless you plan on getting cosmetics or other items).

You won't have to pay a cent to play Dota 2 now!